# sum of 2 asp:textbox values using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

how do i simply type a value in 1 box and have it populate in another using the asp:textbox. I simply want to pull value from 1 asp:textbox and put it in another, ultimately i am going to be adding the sum of 2 boxes and placing it in another, I would like this to happen in real time and not use a button.

Comment: If you want it done real time, take a look at how to read/populate HTML inputs (what an ASP.NET textbox gets rendered as) using javascript.  Once you have tried something and get stuck come back with the code you have and what you are stuck on.

Comment: So where are you struggling with this?

Comment: More info required. Why does this need to be real time?

Comment: @sarin, while there are problems with this question I don't see why that matters.  How would that affect the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTextSource" runat="server" onblur="TextSource_OnBlur(this)" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTextDestination" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TextSource_OnBlur(oElement) {
        var destination = document.getElementById('<%= txtTextDestination.ClientID %>');
        destination.value = oElement.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is really nice but is there a way to have the data fill as i type it, rather then when i click off the <asp:textbox> ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ASP.net, use jQuery for this since it'll avoid post backs.

hook onto the change event of textbox1 and populate text box 2 using jQuery. Try it and let us know.

Comment: Not sure if something this simple requires jQuery.  Could easily be done with plain old javascript.

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Same question can be raised other way!! "Does something this simple requires a page reload"? :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with raja, you should use client side JavaScript (doesn't have to be jQuery) to handle this since it doesn't require server interaction. But let's say for some crazy reason you want it to happen on the server.

```
First Number: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TB1" /><br />
Second Number: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TB2" /><br />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="CalculateBtn" OnClick="CalculateBtn_Click" Text="Calcualte Sum" />
Sum: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="SumTB" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void CalculateBtn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1 = Int32.Parse(TB1.Text);
    int num2 = Int32.Parse(TB2.Text);
    int sum = num1+num2;
    SumTB.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Obviously you can get much more fancy, using doubles instead of ints and verifying that the user typed a valid number and using ScriptMethods or UpdatePanels to do it in real time without the need for a button. But seriously, stick with a client side solution.

Comment: Why don't you use `textbox` leave event? Please read the question properly *" I would like this to happen in real time and **not use a button**"*

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I did read the question. I didn't use it because I'm just providing a short example of how this could be done with server side interaction. As I stated, this question can be much more complex and there's no need to put a ton of work into it if the person asking the question hasn't shown us what they've tried so far. And also as pointed out, a server side solution is most likely unnecessary in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
          $('.amount-input').live('blur', function () {
                  var amountSum = 0;
                       $('.amount-input').each(function () {
                         amountSum += parseInt($(this).val());
                       });

                           $('#<%= Damount.ClientID %>').val(amountSum);
                 enter code here
```

just used java script and called the total amount which is "Damount" from the server code. Still wish it changed in real time except for when i click off the textbox but hey it works!